# EclipseLink-93 Exception Description: The table [item] is not present in this descriptor

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I recently made some changes to a JPA application that has been running fine for a year or so.  I added a couple of new tables and I have run into a few problems.  I can not post a image of my schema as I do not have 10 posts but I have a item table and a product table. Many products can have the same item so the product table has an item_id

The following is my item entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="item")
public class Item implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Integer _id;

private Double carbonValue;

private String description;

private String name;

private Integer discount;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="item")
private Collection<Product> products;

// getters and setters etc
```

And here is my product entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Integer _id;

private Integer deleted;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID", referencedColumnName="_ID")
private Item item;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
@JoinColumn(name="SUPPLIER_ID", referencedColumnName="_ID")
private Supplier supplier;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
private Collection<Consumption> consumptions;
```

I am using eclipselink 2.2

when I run a query on the item table as follows:

```
public final static String SELECT_ALL_ENTITIES_SQL = "SELECT o FROM Item AS o";

public List<Item> getAllEntities() {
        final EntityManager entityManager = DaoUtils.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        final List<Item> items;
        try {
            items = (List<Item>) entityManager.createQuery(SELECT_ALL_ENTITIES_SQL).getResultList();
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }

        return items;
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
 [EL Info]: 2012-10-24 14:16:23.798--ServerSession(1351669994)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913
[EL Severe]: 2012-10-24 14:16:24.16--ServerSession(1351669994)--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [item] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(database.entities.Product --> [DatabaseTable(product)])

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [circle] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(database.entities.Refund --> [DatabaseTable(refund)])

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:230)
    at database.dao.ItemDao.getAllEntities(ItemDao.java:24)
    at database.dao.ItemDao.main(ItemDao.java:19)

Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------


Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [item] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(database.entities.Product --> [DatabaseTable(product)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.tableNotPresent(DescriptorException.java:1628)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.getTable(ClassDescriptor.java:2478)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.buildField(ClassDescriptor.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.buildField(ClassDescriptor.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToManyMapping.initializeTargetForeignKeysToSourceKeys(OneToManyMapping.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToManyMapping.initializeReferenceDescriptor(OneToManyMapping.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.initialize(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.initialize(CollectionMapping.java:1095)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToManyMapping.initialize(OneToManyMapping.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.initialize(ClassDescriptor.java:2744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:230)
    at database.dao.ItemDao.getAllEntities(ItemDao.java:24)
    at database.dao.ItemDao.main(ItemDao.java:19)
```

What have I done wrong here?

UPDATE: on the database I have removed the relationship between product and item.  In my code I have also deleted any reference between the two entities so now the database tables and the entities have no relationship to each other at all.  And I still get the same error?????

SOLVED: When I was coding my entities in another unrelated entity I accendently mislabed an item a product.  I am banging my head on the table now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`. Normally, it is use `JPA Inheritance`. Use `@JoinColumn annotation`

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
private Item item;
```

It is also the same for `Supplier`.

**Update :** It is a issue of `EclipseLink`. [Bug 282571](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=282571)

Try to fix as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
@SecondaryTable(name="item", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="_ID"))
public class Product implements Serializable {
}
```

According to your error log :

```
Exception Description: The table [circle] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(database.entities.Refund --> [DatabaseTable(refund)])
```

You meight need to use `SecondaryTable` annotation in `Refund` entity for `circle`.

Comment: @user1461220 if so, post again your up-to-date coding, `Item` and `Product` with `@JoinColumn`, please.

Comment: it doesnt get as far as running the query, in fact it doesn’t matter what query I run, it can be completely unrelated and I still get the same error

Comment: Thanks for your help CycDemo, When I was coding my entities in another unrelated entity I accendently mislabed an item a product. I am banging my head on the table now.

Answer (score 1):

If `Item` does not need express knowledge of the product it belongs to then `mappedBy` is not required. The `@JoinColumn` in the `Product` table owns this relationship and it makes sense that express knowledge of items is placed here.

So do the following:

Edit the line

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="item")
private Collection<Product> products;
```

To either

```
@OneToMany
private Collection<Product> products;
```

Or better still

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Product> products;
```